# Finding view effects for android

Tags: android, view

Could someone send me links to tutorials for views in general.

What I am hoping is that I add an object on my screen like a right arrow or left arrow for which I would be able to create events for each arrow.

Also if possible could someone link me a tutorial of how animation works with android.

Thank you for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest info is [HERE](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

That explains all about the design for all kind of terminals with android.

Here is the [Basic view tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)

and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) a tutorial to desing in multiple screens sizes

Answer (score 2):

The official [Android Developers' Guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) has got a really good introduction to using all sorts of different types of Views, including layouts, events, widgets, etc.

I'm sure they have things on animation as well, but I haven't looked into it that much.